# How to open `about` addresses on Firefox?

Tags: firefox, autohotkey

I want to use AutoHotKey to open `about` addresses on Firefox, such as `about:config`, `about:preferences`. Using:

- `f10::Run www.google.com`: fine
- `f10::Run about:preferences`: Windows asks me: "You'll need a new app to open this about"
- "f10::Run `about:preferences`" (I can't nest the "`" mark): AutoHotKey says "failed attempt to launch program or document"

Using `Send !to` can only work for `about:preferences` address, and VimFx addon will think the keys are for them.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
f9::Run % A_programfiles "\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe about:preferences"
```

> `A_ProgramFiles` is a built in variable containing the location of your Program Files directory. The above code could be written out in full like:

```
C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe about:preferences
```

> However if your drive letter is different, say `D:\` instead of `C:\`, `A_ProgramFiles` will know this, and point to the correct location, as well it will differentiate between 64 bit OS versions and will point correctly to `C:\Program Files (x86)\`

Comment: Just out of curious, it's your comment ship why does it need to be put in quotes? I feel that without it the text is more natural to read